# How to encode text in C#?

Tags: c#, encoding

I faced a question in an interview test but i got confused and didnt answer that.Can anyone tell me how to encode a text in C#?

The question is :

```
How to encode a following text
a.  U0VDUkVUIENPREUgSVMgTkVYR0VOIElTIFRFU1RJTkc=
```

I tried following code on my own just for try but didnt get any good output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str= "U0VDUkVUIENPREUgSVMgTkVYR0VOIElTIFRFU1RJTkc=";
            byte[] _telnetData;
            _telnetData = new byte[1024];
            _telnetData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine(_telnetData);
           // _networkstream.Write(_telnetData, 0, _telnetData.Length);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I got following output:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: What do you expect to see when you console.writeline byte[] ?

Comment: SECRET CODE IS NEXGEN IS TESTING (before you flag me as random spam, [click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYKXnH))

Comment: Encode to what? There are couple suggestion what this may be *decoded* to, but there is no way to guess how it should be encoded more.

Comment: Encoded?  You are free to use my proprietary algorithm.  The output is `FooU0VDUkVUIENPREUgSVMgTkVYR0VOIElTIFRFU1RJTkc=`. It is a robust algorithm that always encodes the output by prefixing the string `Foo` in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is Base64 encoded text, so you should use `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`.

```
string text = "SECRET CODE IS NEXGEN IS TESTING";

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));
```

The dead giveaway is the characters not being limited to A-F and 0-9, the "=" on the end is not always present, but further suggests base64.

Comment: That would be decoding text, not encoding it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, good point.  I read decode when it said encode.

Answer (score 0):

You already encoded it with this line

```
telnetData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

Now you have the encoded text in a byte array. By definition encoding is converting text to byte array containing the appropriate byte values for the current text.